# How to apply dynamic class in repeater?

Tags: css, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to create a repeater which contains elements with a dynamic class, as well as dynamic background color, and icons (which is put at run-time).
I have a repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repdashboard" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">

          <div if("<%#Eval("id") %>"= 1 ? " class=panel-primary )>
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                        <div class="huge">26</div>
                        <div>'<%#Eval("Tag") %>'!</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="panel-footer" style="color: #337ab7;">
                    <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to apply class on behalf of dynamic value in  div

```
<div if("<%#Eval("id") %>"= 1 ? " class=panel-primary )>
```

when

```
`<%#Eval("id") %> = 1`
```

then apply `class= panel panel-primary`
 and when 
`<%#Eval("id") %> = 2` then apply class=panel panel-green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just write an `if` somewhere in the html and expect it to work. You need a code block.

```
<div class="<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("id")) == 1 ? "panel panel-primary" : "panel panel-green" %>">
```

If you want a lot more evaluations to generate a class, I would recommend a method in code behind.

```
public string AddClass(int id)
{
    if (id == 1)
        return "panel panel-primary";
    else if (id == 2)
        return "panel panel-green";
    else
        return "panel other";
}
```

And then in the Repeater

```
<div class="<%# AddClass(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("id"))) %>">
```

Comment: A small edit wrap code nugget block inside single quote e.g. class='<% ...%>'

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal, That is not true. You use single quotes only if you bind to a property of a Control. The double quotes here are part of the html.

Comment: I see. Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @VDWWD can you help me for one more point how to apply one more else condition on it like if id = 2 then apply panel panel-red and for others  panel panel-green

Comment: Updated my answer. If you have more that 2 options it's easier to create a method.